# Search API Facets: Filtered Results to Map (Leaflet) Shows No Updates to Views Page

Tags: views, search

When using post search results via a Search API Facets for node data, the initial results are displayed as a map content type (Leaflet) but when filtering down to further fields, the results page shows empty (or as set to visitor/location as set in Leaflet style settings in the corresponding View). Ajax is set in Views options.
The Facets, Views pane are set within a Panel Page. The paths show initial correct paths from the Facet link but appear to no show updated data on map.

For example, Widgets with colours of Red, Green, Blue, an initial search for Widgets, shows a Results map in the right pane, with the said Facets to the left, showing 3 Facet result links 1) Red; 2) Green Blue.

The results in the browser bar would show: <domain.com/search-api-results/widget/colour/>

Each Facet link Hover shows a link path as <domain.com/search-api-results/widget/colour/red> etc but then clicking the said link updates the map Views pane to display no results.

I've looked far and wide to find a solution and cannot find why it is doing this and would appreciate as to where I'm going wrong.
This problem was been ongoing for 12 weeks and is holding up my study and needs fixing as of this post date.

Thanks in advance.